# How to route to a same page but with different functionality on different clicks in flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes

I am making an app which has a grid view of around 30 cards and when we tap then on any of them similar page opens with 4 cards but when when click on any of the 4 cards then the link opens in browser based on the the first selection that the user did on the card in the grid view.
The grid view is dynamic built with gridview.builder().
The main thing is how can I pass index to the next pages based on previous clicks.
for eg - suppose the first card is of country and we tap on it than a page opens with population , gdp ,and other options which are same for every country but when we tap on it the data is shown of the country clicked.(this is just for eg, not for actual app)
ps- in my case there is no API we are providing links to the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Navigator.push() to open a new page. You can set up a variable to receive data that you want to display. Since you also use ListView.builder, you have access to index of button clicked.

```
List<Data> data; // let this have data for each button

onPressed(){
    Data dataToBeShown = data[index];
    Navigator.push(
        context, 
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
            ShowData(dataToBeShown),
            ),
        ),
    );
}


class ShowData extends StatefulWidget{
    Data data;
    ShowData(this.Data);
    //other stuff
}
```

Now by clicking each button the Data for that button will be passed as parameter to ShowData